# How to prevent the transfer of package using Scapy module?

Tags: python, scapy

I'm using Scapy (Python) on Linux.

I scan the network traffic using sniff() function and
I want to drop only some of the packets I scanned, Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: By drop do you mean filter the results from sniff() or block traffic?

Comment: @Noob123 Block part of the traffic

Comment: I don't believe you can drop packets with scapy natively.  Are you trying to drop packets from one specific machine or across a network?

Comment: @Noob123 From one specific machine

Comment: Ok.  So I think you really only have two choices.  Either race the response and beat it back to the target with a packet of your own or arp poison the target.  You can use scapy to try and arp poison the target and then respond to their requests.